# Como atribuir uma função a um botão no Django Python

Tags: html, python, funções, django

Estou fazendo um curso de django e gostaria de saber se é possivel atribuir uma função a um botão.

Por exemplo:

```
  <form>
      <label for="word">Digite uma palavra:</label>
      <input id="word" type="text" name="palavra" value="" />
      <input type="submit">                   
  </form>
```

Nessa barra de pesquisa o usuário digitaria uma palavra qualquer. No momento em que esse usuário clicasse em enviar eu gostaria que uma função que eu apelidei de 'Tamanho_da_str' fosse executada:

```
def tamanho_da_str(request):
    palavra_digitada = **Palavra que o usuário digitou na barra de pesquisa**
    len_string = len(palavradigitada)
    dicionario = {'tamanho': len_string}
    return render(request, "resultado.html", dicionario)
```

Para que isso funcionasse eu precisaria estabelecer uma ligação entre o botão enviar e a função tamanho_da_str, depois precisaria que a palavra digitada pelo usuário fosse armazenada na variável palavra_digitada.

Vocês podem me dizer se isso é possível e quais métodos são utilizados ?

Ps : Talvez por não ser um desenvolvedor e não conhecer alguns termos relacionados a área eu não tenha conseguido encontrar nada na internet, mas qualquer direcionamento será bem vindo.

Comment: Opaa Felipe, tudo bem? Pra ser sincero, pelo tempo que desenvolvo em Python e Django eu nunca cheguei a ver um interação entre o botão e uma função no Django, a não ser que você queira adicionar algum dado no Banco de Dados.
Nesse caso você poderia ler um pouco da documentação do próprio Django na parte relacionada aos formulários.
Mas você pode fazer essa função que você deseja com JavaScript!

Comment: Beleza Henrique vou procurar na documentação, mas aproveitando o que você disse sobre salvar no banco de dados, como eu faria isso ? Acho que se eu fizer isso consigo adaptar uma solução para o meu problema. Sobre o JavaScript já ouvi falar mas estou aprendendo o básico do Python ainda, mexer com outra agora ia só me complicar.

Comment: Aí você teria que criar um model e um forms, daí poderia enviar os dados ao banco.
Recomendo seguir o tutorial do Django Girls: https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/pt/django_forms/

Comment: Henrique muito obrigado pela ajuda achei bastante coisa legal na documentação e consegui fazer o que queria usando o método que o Rodrigo informou ali em cima, talvez seja útil para você também, abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como voce já esta programando em Django, é provável que voce ja saiba, mas vou explicitar aqui: O django é chamado de framework MTV (Model-Template-View). A parte referente a view (visão) normalmente inspeciona a solicitação HTTP de entrada e faz queries ou tratam os dados a serem renderizados (apresentação).

Vou apresentar aqui um exemplo que voce pode rodar na sua linha de comando, para simplificar coloquei o exemplo em apenas dois arquivos, mas isso não é a pratica usual no mundo do desenvolvimento django, faço alguns comentários no codigo (os que lembrei) explicando qual seria a convenção adotada pela comunidade, vamos lá:

Arquivo: main.py

```
# Configurações do django, aqui configura-se o projeto django, desde conexoes 
# com banco de dados até recursos estaticos e funcionalidades de internacionalização
# Normalmente, no 'mundo real', essas configuracoes estariam em um arquivo settings.py
from django.conf import settings
import os
ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY = '0uarl&=3a$o1*0wk-5s@x6@d*0%r576h0&@f65+09ebtkv3jtd',
    ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
    MIDDLEWARE = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ),
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [ROOT]
        }
    ]
)

# No mundo real esse codigo estaria em um arquivo views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render 
def index(request):

    count = None
    palavra = None

    if request.method=='POST':
        palavra = request.POST['palavra']
        count = len(palavra)

    return render(request, 'palavra.html', {'count': count, 'palavra': palavra})

# Para conectar a view à estrutura do site é preciso associa-la a uma URL
# No mundo real esse codigo estaria em um arquivo urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = (
    path('', index),
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Arquivo: palavra.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="word">Digite uma palavra:</label>
    <input id="word" type="text" name="palavra" value="" />
    <input type="submit"> 
    {% if count != None %}
        <br><br>
        Palavra digitada: {{palavra}}<br>
        Número de caracteres: {{count}}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Agora rode na sua linha de comando:

```
$ python main.py runserver
```

E voce obtera:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 14, 2019 - 11:55:14
Django version 2.1.1, using settings None
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

No seu browse, aponte para `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
e vc obtera:

[image: Localhost]

Digite por exemplo a palavra "stackoverflow"

E voce obterá:

[image: Digitação da palavra]

Comment: Perfeito, eu já tinha conseguido realizar a tarefa mas você foi extremamente detalhista caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida que eu tive no futuro com certeza vai saber resolver com o seu comentário muito obrigado.

Comment: Na realidade não é um comentário e sim uma resposta, seria interessante que vc desse o aceite e, eventualmente, um upvote em alguma das respostas, para estimular quem tenta ajudar. :-)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda como disse ali no comentário, você recebeu upvote entretanto ele não fica visível por que não tenho 15 reps.

Comment: consegui 15 reps.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
voce usa o metodo POST e assim Django reconhece HTML pelo atributo `name`

```
 <form method = 'POST'>
       {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="word">Digite uma palavra:</label>
      <input id="word" type="text" name="palavra" value="" />
      <input type="submit">                   
  </form>
```

use o `request`

```
def tamanho_da_str(request):

if request.method == 'POST':     
 palavra_digitada = request.POST.get('palavra')
 print (palavra_digitada)
 ....
```

Espero ter ajudado,

E que a força esteja com você

Comment: Bom dia Rodrigo ajudou muito sim mas estou tendo tendo esse erro aqui 'Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.'

Comment: opa eu consegui resolver isso muito obrigado mesmo Rodrigo com essa informação eu vou conseguir fazer muita coisa.

Comment: oi me esqueci de colocar {% csrf_token %}